# How to make my Home button on the menu redirect to my root page

Tags: homepage, home-url

When i create a new page, a permalink is created: `www.example.com?page_id=29`. This page is always pointing to the page which `id` is `29`. Now, i want to point it to the root page in my website: `www.example.com`. I think it has to do with the permalink, but i can't change it. can you help me there please.

Comment: You want to do this dynamically? Every time a new page is created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, just i had to install this [plugin](http://txfx.net/wordpress-plugins/page-links-to/), then when editing the page, in the bottom a new input is added to put on it the link that i want my page point to, in my case i have put `www.mydomainname.com`.
Hope this help people running in the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is unnecessarily complex. If you go into `Settings->Reading` you can set a static homepage and pick which page you want that to be.